# Efficient way to pass data between parent and child element in reactjs [controlled vs uncontrolled components]

Tags: reactjs

I am testing/learning reactjs and making my head around an issue.

Simplified Case:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {...}
    render() {
      return (
        <MyInputs onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <Child onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      )
    }
    
    handleChange() {
        //logic
        processTextAreaText();
    }
} 

class Child extends Component (props) {
  constructor(props) {...}
  render() {
    return (
      <textarea onChange={this.handleChange}"/>
    )
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
    this.props.handleChange(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Dom structure: 
Parent
   Input
   Input
   Child
   Button

I have two inputs, a child element which is textarea and a button. 
User types something in inputs, textarea and clicks the button.

My current idea/solution: On every change in TextArea I am calling the parent changeHandler and saving the value in parent state.

My Question: Is it optimal way? Can I just get the value on button click, and process it directly? How can I get the value from Child element when one clicks the button?

Edit: So far I have read the official reactjs doc [Uncontrolled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

> It can also be slightly less code if you want to be quick and dirty. Otherwise, you should usually use controlled components.

But I still do not get why are uncontrolled components dirty? in case such as mine where I want to get value from texarea only then when I want to process it not when it changes. Isn't saving/updating state in controlled components everytime value changes in textarea unnecessary?

I have read this [article](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/) which is referred in reactjs doc which actually says using uncontrolled components are not bad at all when we just need to know once the value of the element.

But I still do not get why reactjs does not recommend it?
Best,

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is `react way` ([controlled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)). I have read somewhere remarks from react developers but can not find now, may be someone post link. It seems not so efficient but it is worked on client and each change perform not so much data copy in memory. The big text is not so much then 1Mb or more. It will do copy on each key press. It is not so much for actual computers.

Also, of course, you can get a `ref` of your DOM element ([uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)) and take data from it on putton press event without perform copy on each change. It is more efficient.

The `ref` using example:

```js
handleButton = () => {
  console.log(this.refs.textarea.value);
}
render() {
  return (
    <span>
      <textarea ref='textarea'/>
      <button onClick={this.handleButton}/>
    </span>
  )
}
```

Perhaps the term "dirty" confuses. It mean state will be not actual each time and data extraction is performed by user code instead of react. Both approaches have their advantages. Choose what suits you best.

Comment: Hi Thanks. But I still did not get why in official reactjs doc they are saying when we want fast and dirty app, we can use uncontrolled components.

Comment: Unmanaged inputs are not recommended though. They are for special cases only.